# Trying to perform ajax request in Cakephp but will redirect to the link specified in the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to perform ajax request when a link is click passing id value. And try to alert the data if successful. Please tell me what is wrong.
    $('a.view-btn').on('click', function(e){
            var view = $(this);
            var id = view.data('id');

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/bootstrap_exercise/contacts/view/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {product_id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('div#view-contact').load('/bootstrap_exercise/contacts/view .view-contact');
            }
        });
        console.log(id);
    });
```

this is my edit method in controller

```
public function view($id) {         
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->set('contact', $this->request->data('product_id'));
            echo "AJAX SUCCESS";
        } else {
            $this->set('contact', $this->Contact->findById($id));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do return false at the end of the statement.

```
$('form#add_form').on('submit', function(e){
        var thisForm = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: thisForm.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: thisForm.serialize(count),
            success: function() {
                console.log(count);
            } 
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: no need of using both e.preventDefault()  and return false.Both work same

Answer (score 0):

```
//use preventDefault()   
$('form#add_form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var thisForm = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: thisForm.attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: thisForm.serialize(count),
                success: function() {
                    console.log(count);
                } 
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: my fault i put the success function parameter in serialize ^_^